# OpenGL crash on glDrawElements while trying to render Height Map

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, heightmap

I'm writing a class to render a height map from a 32-bit bmp using modern OpenGL techniques. I had it working with immediate mode but wanted to try converting it to a modern OpenGL context. I'm using an element array buffer with the index data for the map and a vbo which has the vertex data where the y component is taken from the height (pixel color) of the bitmap.

Right now, I'm getting an unhandled exception/access violation at the draw call. Here's my code:

```
void HeightMap::initHeightMap(const char* filePath, float size, float height){
SDL_Surface* image = SDL_LoadBMP(filePath);
if (!image)
{
    smodgine::fatalError("Image could not be loaded!");
}

std::vector<float> tmp;
for (int y = 0; y< image->h; y++)
{
    tmp.clear();
    for (int x = 0; x < image->w; x++)
    {
        Uint32 pixel = ((Uint32*)image->pixels)[y * image->pitch/4 + x];
        Uint8 r, g, b;
        SDL_GetRGB(pixel, image->format, &r, &g, &b);

        tmp.push_back((float)r / 255.0f);
    }
    heights.push_back(tmp);
}

for (int z = 0; z < heights.size(); z++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < heights[0].size(); x++)
    {
        vertices.push_back(x * size);
        vertices.push_back(heights[z][x] * height);
        vertices.push_back(z * size);
    }
}

if (_vbo == 0) {
    glGenBuffers(1, &_vbo);
}

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

_numRows = heights.size() - 1;
_numColumns = heights[0].size() - 1;

SDL_FreeSurface(image);

createElementBuffer();
}

void HeightMap::renderHeightMap()
{
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vbo);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _eleBuffer);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
}

void HeightMap::createElementBuffer()
{
for (int z = 0; z < _numRows; z++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < _numColumns; x++)
    {
        //top left
        indices.push_back(z * _numRows + x);
        //bottom left
        indices.push_back((z + 1) * _numRows + x);
        //top right
        indices.push_back(z * _numRows + (x + 1));

        //top right
        indices.push_back(z * _numRows + (x + 1));
        //bottom left
        indices.push_back((z + 1) * _numRows + x);
        //bottom right
        indices.push_back((z + 1) * _numRows + (x + 1));
    }
}

if (_eleBuffer == 0){
    glGenBuffers(1, &_eleBuffer);
}

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _eleBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

I've only been using modern OpenGL for about a week or so, any help is appreciated :D

Answer (score 3):

You're using the `sizeof` operator for instances of `std::vector`, expecting that it will give you the size of the data in the vector:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
...
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

That will not produce the expected result. `sizeof` gives you the size in memory of the `vector` object, not of the data stored in the vector. That data is dynamically allocated, and not stored in the `vector` instance itself.

To get the correct size, you can use:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(vertices[0]), vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
...
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(indices[0]), indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that makes alot of sense. However, I changed it and am still getting a crash...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, other than the bug that Reto Koradi helped me with, in another part of my code (during the main function) i had accidentally been calling glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)